# How to set system property values in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I 'm following a tutorial about JAAS Authentication [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) and when it shows how to run the example code, says that the compiled class should be launched with a standard option of Java launcher which is -Djava.security.auth.login.config==sample_jaas.config . In this way a system property will be set:

```
java -Djava.security.auth.login.config==sample_jaas.config sample.SampleAcn
```

I did it with this way, but now I want to run the code in NetBeans too. Since NetBeans use Ant I think specifying these options may be different. I looked at the options menus in NetBeans but didn't find anything.
How could I set this property when running with NetBeans?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- You can right click on the project, and select `Properties`.
- Click on `Run` category and insert you configuration in `VM Options`
- For instance, in your case, paste: `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=sample_jaas.config`

You've to use `=` not `==`.