# How to Change voice of TTS for Java

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, freetts

I am using FreeTTS to speak out some text in my java program. I want to embed MBROLA Voices in it. I followed [the instructions](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/mbrola/README.html), but I got stuck here:

> **Enable FreeTTS Support for MBROLA**
>
> To enable FreeTTS support for MBROLA, merely copy mbrola/mbrola.jar to lib/mbrola.jar. Then, whenever you run any FreeTTS application, specify the "mbrola.base" directory as a system property:
>
> `java -Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola -jar bin/FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar
>   mbrola_us1`

In the tutorial what they are doing is, they type this line in cmd to make a jar file speak in the voice they are telling (us1) but what i have to do is that, i already have a java program and i want to change the voice it speaks.
How to do this?

I tried to change the vm options but that does not help.

Note: I am using Netbeans IDE and i also have the file 'FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar'

So in short, i am looking for a clear explanation on how to proceed/add MBROLA Voices into FreeTTS library in java(for a newbie)...

What do you say? should i consider changing my OS to Ubuntu for Java Development???

Comment: you would type the command in a command line tool.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838912/how-to-set-system-property-values-in-netbeans

Answer (score 4):

Into the terminal:-)This means you need to run your program from command line, [here](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html) is nice tutorial how to do that.

But I think it can be also run from the NetBeans, go to the `Properties` of your project, go to `Run` and paste `-Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola` into `VM options`. You will of course need `FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar` on the classpath (you can add it through `Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder`).

Comment: What do you mean by "You will of course need FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar on the classpath." - i dint get you

Comment: Exactly "FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar"??

Comment: It's a library you are passing to your command so I guess you need it in order to run your application.

Comment: Sure, the GUI will help you select it:)

Comment: Cant i type the whole "java -Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola -jar bin/FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar mbrola_us1 yourJavaClass" instead of just "-Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola"??

Comment: No, you can't, `java` is a tool which comes directly from JRE and it's meant to run compiled Java programs. And it can have various parameters, one of them is `-DtypeAnyPropertyYouWant` and this is what you need to fill in in the NetBeans `VM options` field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44424/discussion-between-daksh-shah-and-petr-mensik)

Answer (score 1):

-D is used to provide a system property to your java program. So you need to provide it while running your java program:

```
java -Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola -jar bin/FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar mbrola_us1 yourJavaClass
```

If you are using an IDE such as eclipse  then you can do the same by going to:

> Run -> Run configurations, select project, second tab: “Arguments”.
>   Top box is for your program, bottom box is for VM arguments, e.g.
>   -Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola -jar bin/FreeTTSHelloWorld.jar mbrola_us1

Comment: @DakshShah follow the step as I have mentioned for eclipse

Comment: Petr Mensik said i have to add just "-Dmbrola.base=/home/jim/mbrola".. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "your/mbrola/base/directory");
    VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    String voice = "mbrola_us1";
    Voice helloVoice = voiceManager.getVoice(voice);
    if (helloVoice == null) {
        Voice[] availableVoices = voiceManager.getVoices();
        List<String> voiceList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Voice v : availableVoices) voiceList.add(v.getName());
        System.out.println("Not a valid voice: " + voice + "\nValid voices: " + voiceList);
        return;
    }
    helloVoice.allocate();

    /* Synthesize speech. */
    helloVoice.speak("Thank you for giving me a voice. " + "I'm so glad to say hello to this world.");

    /* Clean up and leave. */
    helloVoice.deallocate();
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit complicated, so i will set up a new separate project to test this out first; so i have to create a new project according to FreeTTS, make sure that FreeTTS Work and then follow the tutorial, download the voices and MBROLA and all and then copy paste this code?

Comment: @DakshShah You can just insert that code in your existing Java program - the if block is not required, it is there in case `mbrola_us1` is not found, to show you what other voices are available. Note that I have never used that library or tested that code but based on their tutorial it should work.

Comment: Can you please help me, with chatting? if you are free

Comment: @DakshShah In the tutorial you linked, it is the "*base directory to put both MBROLA binary and MBROLA voice databases*" that they call `/home/jim/mbrola`. So wherever you placed those files.

Comment: I am using windows and those guys are using MAC, so when i was following the tutorial again this time, they said that download the binaries install them and then in a folder do all that stuff. Maybe for mac users this makes sense but not for me. When i went to their downloads for windows, they had a exe, i downloaded and installed it. But where is that folder they keep talking about is? I also looked up at the place i have installed it (in C Drive) in a README they said if you have unpacked the rar successfully... but there is no RAR. What to do? I am a windows guy. (Sorry if i sound lame)

Comment: And if i compare files listed in the tutorial with the place my files installed some of them are same but the thing is that the main file is mbroli.exe (i can send a list of all if req.) but if it is so it is just a click and run application :P

Comment: Not sure to be honest - I have not used that library so I don't know how to install it... Sorry I could not help.

Comment: No No you did help, i will figure that part out on myself; tell me that if my folder resides in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mbrola Tools" do i have to type this in java?

Comment: You can try `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mbrola Tools"` or `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mbrola Tools"` - one of the two should work.

Comment: and also... your "List<String> voiceList = new ArrayList<>();" shows error; can you please tell me what should be the correct line instead of this

Comment: Yah i already tried with "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mbrola Tools" [studied about these escape characters in C :P]

Comment: @DakshShah The error on list can be either because you are missing an import or because you use Java 6 or below (in which case it's time to upgrade!): in that case, try `List<String> voiceList = new ArrayList<String>();` instead.

Comment: it shows error:
    run:

    Could not validate any MBROLA voices at

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Mbrola Tools

    Make sure you FULLY specify the path to
    the MBROLA directory using the mbrola.base
        system property.

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at embed.Embed.main(Embed.java:20)
    Java Result: 1

Comment: At least it seems to have read the directory properly. Not sure what those files are - are you sure there are in that folder?

Comment: Yes they are but the main file is mbroli.exe and not some mbrola(there is one mbrola.txt) so i think that is the problem. But if i rename mbroli.exe to mbrola.exe and run the java program the java program executes by opening me up the mbrola.exe and poping some msg in it and then if i close that window, it ends with "Processing Utterance: com.sun.speech.freetts.ProcessException: No audio data read" in Netbeans. By the way, that mbroli.exe opens some kind of windows in which you can enter the text and then click the speak button. a view (https://www.dropbox.com/s/3a1chbhpj90a0li/Mbroli.png)

Comment: But the drawback in mbroli is that, that right now it just shows us1 not us2 and us3 and it is also not able to speak out anything. but i can make that work(it once worked yesterday but i have reinstalled; but i think i can make that work) but the point is that what i want is that like in the sample program it should say that text "Hello wor...." in a nice (us1) voice directly and not open a separate window for user to enter the text.. :(