# how could I perform the command line argument " java -Djava.security.manager GetProps" but using NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

I'm currently studying java security on [Java tutorial Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/step2.html). I was just wondering, for the following command line arguments, how could I achieve the same purpose, but using NetBeans IDE? What do I have to do with NetBeans to achieve the same effect?

> To execute the GetProps application with the default security manager,
>   type the following:
>
> java -Djava.security.manager GetProps

Comment: Is that what are you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838912/how-to-set-system-property-values-in-netbeans

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans how to set command line arguments in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168759/netbeans-how-to-set-command-line-arguments-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little late but for anyone else who needs the information, right click on your project, select "Properties", click "Run" on the right, and put whatever your command line arguments are, in this case "-Djava.security.manager", under "VM Options". Also, be sure to run your project through "Run Project" (The green arrow) and not "Run File".